# how to limit keys of an object to a list of set strings in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an api that can return one of the following:

`{ fill: 'string'}` or `{stroke: 'string'}` or `{effect: 'string'}`

I have the following type for the key:

```
type StyleKeyType =
  | 'fill'
  | 'stroke'
  | 'effect';
```

and I'd like to create a type for the object. I tried:

```
type StylesObject = { [K in StyleKeyType]?: string };
```

but this fails as it thinks that `{}` is valid where in my case it is not.

Is there a way to generate this type without manually spelling out each of the possible object types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is valid because `StylesObject` has marked all of its properties as optional `?`.

Here is one option that will work for you:

```
type StylesObject = {
  [key in StyleKeyType]: Record<key, string>
}[StyleKeyType];
```